# Why "top-only" rectangle border changes to "bottom-only" when I save theme.res file?

Tags: codenameone

I have created a custom style with rectangular border. I've set the border to be 'top-only'. Then I saved the theme.res file. Built and run the app and it works fine, the border is 'top-only'. After that, when I open theme.res file and just save it, it automatically changes 'top-only' to 'bottom-only' border. It gets very annoying to change it back to 'top-only'. Could you have a look at it? I'm using Windows 10, Netbeans

Comment: Can you file an issue? 
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/
Also please state the version of the designer tool you're using, it might differ from the plugin version.